# Google Sheets - Query + ImportRange - do not act as required

Tags: google-sheets

I have the following formula in a spreadsheet

```
 =QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("URL", "Sheet1!A1:E"); IMPORTRANGE("URL", "Sheet2!A2:E")},"Select *")
```

Under normal conditions this should import all contents of both sheets up to column E. However, it only adds one sheet, indifferent of which one I put first, it only picks up the first argument of the query.

Can anyone help me with this?

query has 2 importrange arguments, and should display them both. however, this only pick ups one. any ideas?

Comment: I assume it is importing both sheet data. As you are stacking data, it is showing null rows of first sheet and stack data of another sheet. Try to filter null rows in query part. Give a try `=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("URL", "Sheet1!A1:E"); IMPORTRANGE("URL", "Sheet2!A2:E")},"Select * where Col1 is not null")`

Comment: `However, it only adds one sheet,` Most unlikely. The "problem" is that your import ranges are open-ended, so they import as many rows of data as there are rows in each sheet. If a row is blank, it still gets imported; so there could be many, many blank rows between the last row of data of Sheet1 and the first row of data of Sheet2. @Harun24hr has shown you the solution.